# macOS Mail has started to delete incoming mail unexpectedly

Tags: mail.app, email, imap, spam, macos

I have started noticing that email comes into Mail that gets nearly immediately deleted. I notice it either by the system level notification, or looking at the mailbox I see that it comes in. Then in less than one second, the mail disappears.

That is, the mail is not anywhere in any mailbox. In particular, it is not in my Today smart mailbox, which should show everything, even spam.

So IT IS NOT IN MY SPAM FOLDER.

I have re-checked all of my rules, and none of them permanently delete mail, although there are a few that move mail to Trash.

I am wondering if this could be caused by the IMAP server in any way. For example, there would have to be some automated action that causes the server to deliver the mail, then delete it.

I do have multiple mail services. I cannot tell for sure if the disappearing mail is confined to a specific service, but it seems like it is related to one of them: comcast.net.

I have checked the setting on the webmail service for Comcast.net, and I don't see anything that would cause such automated deletions.

Comment: When you temporarily disable the rules, does the bad behavior continue?

Comment: @IconDaemon you are pointing out a great troubleshooting step. Unfortunately if I disable all my rules, this would be a serious drawback to my work. Even that would be ok if it was a short time. But I did not mention it but it is not that common and it would take quite a while to have it happen, plus I would have to be monitoring the inbox constantly to see if the problem occurs. Nevertheless, I might be forced to take a drastic step such as you suggest.

Comment: Is it a wide assortment of senders (if you can tell) or one particular (or a small subset) sender?

Comment: It is more than one sender. I have specifically observed the files being received and deleted from two unrelated senders. The problem is that if this action occurs when I am not watching for it, there is no trace in the system that it has happened. So I cannot put an accurate scope on it.